# x, y座標とその座標の値のデータをマッピングする方法

Tags: python, numpy

現在Pythonで座標データをマッピングしようとしています。
具体的には、

```
x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1])
z = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

`x`はx軸の値、`y`はy軸の値、`z[i]`は座標(`x[i], y[i]`)での値です。これを

```
result = np.array([[0, 0, 3, 0],
                   [4, 5, 0, 0],
                   [3, 4, 0, 1],
                   [2, 0, 0, 2]])
```

のようにxとy座標の位置にzの値を入れる処理をしようとしています。
xとyに座標がないところは0を入れます。
何かいいアイデアはないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

左下が原点になっていますので、それを考慮しています。

```py
>>> result = np.zeros((max(y)+1, max(x)+1), dtype=int)
>>> result[len(result)-(y+1), x] = z
>>> result
array([[0, 0, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 0, 2]])
```